# unable to install anything that depends upon spamassassin. Cant even install spamassasin

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to install `mailscanner` using `apt-get install mailscanner` and I got the following error

```
Setting up spamassassin (3.3.1-1) ...
Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: child process [21344] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 2588.
invoke-rc.d: initscript spamassassin, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing spamassassin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailscanner:
 mailscanner depends on spamassassin (>= 3.1); however:
  Package spamassassin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mailscanner (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 spamassassin
 mailscanner
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I tried to install `spamassassin` I got the following error :

```
Setting up spamassassin (3.3.1-1) ...
Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: child process [21389] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 2588.
invoke-rc.d: initscript spamassassin, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing spamassassin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailscanner:
 mailscanner depends on spamassassin (>= 3.1); however:
  Package spamassassin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mailscanner (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 spamassassin
 mailscanner
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 10.04

Comment: Problem seems to be solved. I did apt-get install --purge spamassassin after stopping the service.

Comment: Have you tried -f?. I mean 'apt-get -f install mailscaner'

Comment: @Harbhag - could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved. I did `apt-get install --purge spamassassin` after stopping the service.

Comment: Great :) Please mark this question as solved (use the gray/green button left to the answer).